# Grails using inconsistent redirect uri when for the same controller

Tags: grails, redirect, groovy, controller, http-status-code-404

I've got a simple controller in my Grails app with simple mappings...

```
TCacheController {
  def index ={}
  def list= {}
```

}

```
"/tcache/" (controller: "TCache"){
   action = [GET: "index"]
}

"/tcache/items" (controller: "TCache"){
   action = [GET: "list"]
}
```

All of my URL's are of the form http://.../tcache/*, and everything works fine. The problem arises when I use `<g:actionSubmit>` in a view like this...

```
<g:form controller="TCache">

   <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="list" value="List Items">
```

The submit works, but in my list action I have a redirect in case something goes wrong, and that redirect is resulting in 404 because Grails is sending to `/TCache/..`, not `/tcache/...`

Under what circumstances is Grails changing upper/lower case of the URI, and is there a way to force it to always use `/tcache`? I tried using controller="tcache" in the form, but then the action stops working, probably because Grails can't find the controller.

Comment: What does the code for the redirect in your list action look like?

Comment: The code for the `list` action basically goes and gets some data then does a `render[view:'list']` which goes to `list.gsp`. If any exceptions occur in the action, I catch it and do a `redirect(action:'index')`, and that's when I get the 404 because it tries to redirect to `/TCache/...` when it should be redirecting to `/'tcache/...`, I'm trying to figure why it's using upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out on my own. Grails' convention over configuration is great, but sometimes Grails does not always guess correctly.

In the controller, when rendering a view, using literal paths ensures that Grails will not have to guess anything...

```
TCacheController {
  def index ={}
  def list= {
     render( view: "/tcache/listitems", model:[])
}
```

instead of...

```
render( view: "listitems", model:[])
```

In my case, having multiple controllers, it appears Grails got a bit confused and attempted to prefix `/TCache/..` for the full render view path when it should have used `/tcache/listitems`.